# Не могу настроить Intellij IDEA и JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я только начал свой путь в программировании и начал я его с установки JDK и IDEA, но вот не задача, так как я полный профан, то не понимаю почему я не могу запустить свой первый хелоу ворлд?
я покопался в интернете, что нужно настроить переменные среды,это было сделано, однако без результата, потом посмотрел по поводу библиотек, вроде что-то добавил(package), один фиг еррор уже другой .
Я теперь не совсем понимаю что я должен сделать.
Винда 10, комп собрал себе сам возможно какого-то софта не хватает [image: САМА ошибка[![после того как дописал недостающий пакет[![настроенные(вроде как норм) мной переменные среды[![даже догадался поднять их приоритет подняв их вверх]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoVFt.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBxVG.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihmt4.png)

Comment: На 3 скрине - явная ошибка. Пакет может быть только один. На 4 - всё правильно в коде. Но яву - да, похоже не видит. Попробуйте не использовать последнюю версию - там может быть много нюансов. Поставьте 8 версию. Её, возможно, надо ещё и в IDE прописать в настройках проекта. Также проверьте, что ява вообще встала: в консоли `java -v` (вроде). Также, возможно, надо главный класс проекта указать как-то. Точнее не скажу - за годы практики ни разу не запускал метод `main`, ибо всё всегда системы сборки делают сами через фреймворки.

Comment: на 4 printLn с большой буквой, а чего он System и String выделил, пока не видно